# user account name of computer from ip address in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to track which user account on the same pc is using my software which is an web application. Is this possible? I can only get computer name but not user account name. I need to find out whether it is administrator or guest.

Comment: Using Windows Authentication?

Comment: There are several institutions which do not comply with the Windows user policy - one user is (sometimes automatically) logged into Windows, but when specialzed applications (hospital information system) are started, each user has to use his/her specific login for that application. That is: one Windows user, several users of a specific application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and it worked perfectly.

```
public static string GetIP4Address()
    {
        string IP4Address = String.Empty;

        foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress))
        {
            if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
            {
                IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (IP4Address != String.Empty)
        {
            return IP4Address;
        }

        foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
        {
            if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
            {
                IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return IP4Address;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve this is by using Windows Authentication in you web application. Then you can check all claims available to this user.

**Note**: For this to work the server and the client must be on either the same domain, or domains with trust between them.

Comment: What do you mean? Does the windows authentication only work for local users on the server? Or do you not get any information about the user (using windows authentication) when the user is not on the server?